# Record Server Interaction of Hessian based Server Communication for VUGen

Tags: hessian

Does anybody know of a way to record hessian based server interaction so that it can be used for load tests using Mercury Virtual User Generator (VUGen)?

Possibly something using a logging proxy and generating code for direct submission of the hessian post requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The User Support doesn't help very much with that but recommends to open a request for improvement if one is interested in such a feature.

Looks like we are going to implement our own implementation based on the TeeOutputStream http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/output/TeeOutputStream.html